# Autocompletion / Suggestion / Intellisense for Javascript in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, plugins, autocomplete, tooltip

I just want to know if it is possible to get a plugin (I searched but not found) in VSCode to get all the JavaScript native methods for objects in suggestion.

Example for `obj.hasOwnProperty`

[image]

### Sample Code:

```
let obj = {
    count : 0
}
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty)
```

My plugins

[image]

JavaScript has so many native methods, it would so much easier to learn these with a good autocomplete plugin and tooltips.

Comment: You're looknig for, ES6 snippets vs code extention

Comment: I already have this. Is it possible to have conflict with another plugin?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the tabnine extension would help with this.

The tabnine extension is AI powered so it should recommend a suggestion.

You can download it either form the vscode stor or from herehttps://www.tabnine.com/install/vscode

Comment: The free version won't help unless I already know the method

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your example code with the vscode extension named "`Tabnine AI Autocomplete for Javascript`..." and it works like a charm.

But in order to use it you need to create an account on tabnine website.

First install the extension and it will show you a notification on the vscode left sidebar. Click on that notification and login with google or github and you are done.

Here is the full name of the extension and a link to the official resource.

```
Tabnine AI Autocomplete for Javascript, Python, Typescript, PHP, Go, Java, Ruby & more
```

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TabNine.tabnine-vscode

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your '**settings.json**' file with this one. It will remove your custom settings though.

**File > Prefrences > Settings > Open Settings (Json)**

**Note:** You'll find this 'Open Settings' in the top right corner hover on the buttons.

```
{
  "editor.fontSize": 12,
  "files.autoSave": "off",
  "editor.tabSize": 1,
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 12,
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
  },
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
  "prettier.semi": false,
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "editor.cursorBlinking": "expand",
}
```